# Does Entity Framework change the default return value of a SQL Stored Procedure from 0 to -1?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

Trying to troubleshoot a return value problem and it appears as though EF4 doesn't handle the return value from a stored procedure as expected.

When I run just the stored Procedure from SQL server management studio the return value is zero.  this is expected.  However, when I run the code from my service the same stored procedure call returns -1 instead.

```
using (var ctx = new LAMSEntities())
            {
                ObjectParameter tempComputerId = new ObjectParameter("computerId", Guid.Empty);
                ObjectParameter tempCustomerId = new ObjectParameter("customerId", string.Empty);

                result = ctx.RegisterCustomerComputer_i(regCode, machineHashId, tempComputerId, tempCustomerId);

                if (result != 0)  //0 = success in SQL Stored Procedures
                    ///TODO:  may want to add logging at this point to determine what the cause of failure was.
                    return null;

                CustomerRegistration cr = new CustomerRegistration();
                cr.ComputerHash = machineHashId;
                cr.ComputerId = Guid.Parse(tempComputerId.Value.ToString());
                cr.CustomerId = tempCustomerId.Value.ToString();
                cr.RegistrationCode = regCode;
                cr.RegistrationDate = DateTime.Now;

                return cr; 
            }
```

this is the code from my service call.  The RegisterCustomerComputer_i is the stored procedure.  Any suggestions or insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

TRY

```
 ctx.RegisterCustomerComputer_i(regCode, machineHashId, tempComputerId, tempCustomerId).First();
```